# Replacing special character with JavaScript, not working with on Samsung S3 Browser

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace special character with blank via a

```
$('#replacedInput').keyup(function() {
      var $th = $(this);
      $th.val($th.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, function(str) { 
      return ''; }
      ) );
 });
```

this is working in all browser except Samsung S3 mobile.

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think `setTimeout`, with value `1` will help you for this

Comment: Have you tried using `keydown` instead of `keyup`?

Comment: Might we know why you are trying to do this? For example, in the replace call, why not simply use '' rather than a function which returns that? Also, try posting your real scenario : Are you simply trying to disallow all non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: @chandranshu YES "I am trying to replace special character with blank"

Comment: You haven't answered my first question in the comment i.e. why are you not simply using `replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g,'')`?

Comment: @chandranshu Is that answer my question ?

Comment: @rab i can not add delay in my code sorry.

Comment: @RenatoZannon keydown working same for me.